# How to find out number of solutions for equations of type $a+b^2+c^3+d^4 \le X$?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Given the value of 'X' how do we calculate the number of solutions of the equation 
$$a+b^2+c^3+d^4 \le X$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are non negative integer values?
What are these type of equations called and the concept of mathematics that deals with these type of equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about the background of these equations, but finding general solutions can be done by induction on the degree of the "polynomial".

First consider $a\leq X$, clearly this has $X+1$ solutions.
Now consider $a+b^{2}\leq X$ which is equivalent to $a\leq X-b^{2}$. Then $b\in\{0,...,\lfloor\sqrt{X}\rfloor\}$, so there are 
$$\sum^{\lfloor\sqrt{X}\rfloor}_{i=0}X-i^{2}+1$$
solutions.

Continue this process to find the solution to the "polynomial" of degree 4.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped a lot. :)